# Botfather step-by-step bot (telegram/ruby)

Tags: ruby, telegram, telegram-bot

I've really been dragging myself from asking this question here, but after googling forever I feel It's needed. So:

I'm trying to build a bot with a similar structure as the Botfather in telegram. I'd like to enable a step by step configuration for users using my bot. So if I ask "What's your email?" I'd like them to naturally be able to answer that and I'll know what question they answered. And that's the problem, I can't seem to figure out a good structure for knowing which question they answered and what to trigger. All documentation in every bot I've scanned simply use a structure like this:

```
if message.text == 'london'
  bot.api.send_message(chat_id: message.chat.id, text: 'Correct!')
end
```

And this is not very beneficial when I don't know what the user will write or if I have duplicated accepted answers for different questions. I've tried using replies and ForceReply etc, but this also creates a weird structure and don't look as clean in the feed as natural messages.

Simply put: How do I know if a message goes together with a question and then trigger something?

Sorry for a somewhat unstructured question, hopefully one of you awesome people have an answer to my issue.

Comment: There are probably better forums for questions such as these since this is unstructured as you note, but why cant question be a variable you are comparing as well, why couldnt a q/a pair be a dictionary? question => answer. You are not limited to one conditional in an if.

Comment: You need a structure to track what question was asked of whom and then later you can compare the answer. You'll need to sketch in some more code.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please edit your question to show your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my bot I'm creating a "TelegramChat" recod in DB and store in "AwaitingReplyTo" field a reference to a "question" and some related information (for example id of an account that need to be updated).

Something like:

```
def ask_question(question):
  ...
  telegram_chat_record(chat_id).awaiting_reply_to = "question:" + question
  telegram_chat_record.save_to_db()
  ...

def dispatcher(update):
  telegram_chat_record = get_telegram_chat_record(update)
  if telegram_chat_record.awaiting_reply_to == "question:What is your favorite city?":
    check_reply_to_favorite_city(update)
  ...
```

Comment: This is great! I started building on something similar and this made the cream on the cake. You sir, are awesome! Thanks!